# Spring servlet URL mapping

Tags: spring, rest, url, servlets, request-mapping

I need to add Restful URL in existing spring based web service.

Each URL is well mapped but after clicking Restful URL such as
http://localhost:9090/Mercury/rest/invoice, 
all contextroot path is changed as http://localhost:9090/Mercury/rest

The point is that I want to use both restful(/rest) and *.do URL pattern

How can I set contextroot path up without /rest ?

web.xml

```
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class InvoiceController {

@RequestMapping(value="/{name}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getInvoice(@PathVariable String name, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("name", name);

    return "rest.body";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer `Spring Pet Clinic` on github, to learn how to configure various views.[Sample view  config xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring/mvc-view-config.xml). Here is the outline.

> The ContentNegotiatingViewResolver delegates to the
>   InternalResourceViewResolver and BeanNameViewResolver, and uses the
>   requested media type (determined by the path extension) to pick a
>   matching view. When the media type is 'text/html', it will delegate to
>   the InternalResourceViewResolver's JstlView, otherwise to the
>   BeanNameViewResolver.